# Bug in Groovy private fields causes strange behaviour?

Tags: groovy

It seems like adding the private keyword to class fields yields strange behaviours. The follow code breaks when the private keyword is used and is fine otherwise. Can someone please confirm this?

```
@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
class Cell{
    private int x; //adding private keyword to the fields causes test to give a false    positive
    private int y; //adding private keyword to the fields causes test to give a false positive

    Cell(_x,_y){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }    
}

def liveCells = [] as Set

Cell cell = new Cell(0,0);
Cell diffCell = new Cell(1,1);

liveCells.add(cell)
assert liveCells.contains(cell) == true
assert liveCells.contains(diffCell) == false //test fails due to private keyword to the fields. remove private keywords and the test passes.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EqualsAndHashCode by default won't include any private fields, so you need tell it to do so:

```
@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode( includeFields=true )
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) As I'm new to groovy, may I know where to learn more about such annotations/Apis and their usage? [Groovy document](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html) does not mention anything about (includeFields = true). Thanks once again for your help. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, it does mention includeFields all the way at the bottom of the page. But it seems that all fields (irregardless if its public or private) are by default not included. Is my understanding wrong? Or is the document incorrect? :P